# Latex stops referencing theorem environment

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

I'm resuming a project after some weeks.

Now, when I reference some theorem, the result are that bored question marks (??). For theorems that already exists, refence to that works well, but referencing other theorems doesn't.

It's weird. Before all was fine.

For example:

```
\begin{def:conv_method_1}

...

\end{def:conv_method_1}

...

Theorem~\ref{def:conv_method_1}
```

and the result is

```
Theorem ??
```

Any trick?

Comment: What packages are you using? Should your theorem definition say `\begin{theorem}\label{def:conv_method_1}` instead of `\begin{def:conv_method_1}`?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I suggest you post that as an answer in its own right so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your theorem definition should say `\begin{theorem}\label{def:conv_method_1} ...` instead of `\begin{def:conv_method_1} ...`.